# cpp: Problema con un while y un o lógico con caracteres

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, gcc

Hola estoy probando cosas con `C++` y me he encontrado que en el siguiente código no sale del bucle.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char chr1;

    while ( chr1 != 'y' || chr1 != 'n' ) {
        cout << "Intro a char: (y/n) ";
        cin >> chr1;
        if (chr1 == 'y') {
            cout << "yes" << endl;
        } else if ( chr1 == 'n' ) {
            cout << "no" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "repeat please..." << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Curiosamente, si sólo escribo una de las opciones funciona bien, pero cuando meto el `OR` no sale del `while` (de momento solo me ha pasado con caracteres), se que conforme tengo montada esta estructura lo suyo es cambiar el `while` por un *boleano* y que cuando entre en el if lo pase a false, pero esa estructura if no debería de estar.

Esto me ha pasado usando `CodeBlocks`, `DevC++`, ambos con MinGW en diferentes equipos con Windows.

Comment: y que es lo que intentas conseguir? Escribir `y` o `n` y que se salga del bucle?

Comment: Si, ese es el plan

Answer (score 1):

Para que se salga de bucle tienes que cambiar el operador `OR` a `AND`

```
while ( chr1 != 'y' && chr1 != 'n' ) {
```

De esta manera al escribir `y` o `n` saldrá del bucle, en cambio si escribimos otro carácter, nos saldrá el mensaje de volver a repetir el carácter

**Código completo:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char chr1;

    while ( chr1 != 'y' && chr1 != 'n' ) {
        cout << "Intro a char: (y/n) ";
        cin >> chr1;
        if (chr1 == 'y') {
            cout << "yes" << endl;
        } else if ( chr1 == 'n' ) {
            cout << "no" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "repeat please..." << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

En cambio si lo que quieres es que se salga del bucle al introducir un caracter diferente de `y` o `n` seria así:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char chr1;

    while ( chr1 != 'y' || chr1 != 'n' ) {
        cout << "Intro a char: (y/n) ";
        cin >> chr1;
        if (chr1 == 'y') {
            cout << "yes" << endl;
        } else if ( chr1 == 'n' ) {
            cout << "no" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "out" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Podremos la instrucción `break` para salir del bucle al comprobar que el carácter escrito es diferente al que queremos.

Comment: Pero si haces un AND ambos tienen que ser correctos, si no recuerdo mal, mientras que un OR debería de ser que una de las condiciones sea cierta.

Answer (score 1):

En lógica booleana, una condición unida por *Or* es verdadera si una de las condiciones a cada lado del operador lógico es verdadera, esta es su tabla de la verdad:

```
+------ Condición ------+ Resultado +
|     falso O falso     |   falso   |
|   falso O verdadero   | verdadero |
|   verdadero O falso   | verdadero |
| verdadero O verdadero | verdadero |
```

Ahora vamos a usar esta tabla de la verdad sobre tu condición:

```
while ( chr1 != 'y' || chr1 != 'n' ) {
```

Viene a decir: "*Si `chr1` es diferente de `'y'` o si `chr1` es diferente de `'n'`: sigue*".

Vamos a suponer que se introduce `'x'`:

- ¿`'x'` es diferente de `'y'`? Verdadero.
- ¿`'x'` es diferente de `'n'`? Verdadero.
- ¿Verdadero o verdadero? Verdadero, sigue.

Vamos a suponer que se introduce `'y'`:

- ¿`'y'` es diferente de `'y'`? Falso.
- ¿`'y'` es diferente de `'n'`? Verdadero.
- ¿Falso o verdadero? Verdadero, sigue.

Vamos a suponer que se introduce `'n'`:

- ¿`'n'` es diferente de `'y'`? Verdadero.
- ¿`'n'` es diferente de `'n'`? Falso.
- ¿Verdadero o falso? Verdadero, sigue.

---

La única manera de que tu bucle acabase, sería que ambas expresiones a cada lado del Or fuesen falsas, pero es imposible que suceda jamás porque `chr1` no puede ser a la vez `'y'` y `'n'`. Puedes [solucionar el problema siguiendo los consejos de Mario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/270711/2742).